# private method `chomp' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to learn Ruby by converting a Java program to Ruby, but I've been coming up with an error surrounding this block of code:

```
  def create
    @user_input = String.new()
#   @word_arr = Array.new

  print "Enter the text to be converted to pig latin, EOF to quit: "
    while gets do
      STDOUT.flush
      @user_input = gets.chomp
      @word_arr = @user_input.string.split(' ')
      @word_arr.each { |x| puts x.engToLatin() + ' '}
      print "EOF to Quit"
      @user_input = ""

    end

  end
```

I've been getting this error:

```
EnglishToPigLatin.rb:14:in `create': private method `chomp' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from EnglishToPigLatin.rb:60
```

This is the area around line 60:

```
#if __FILE__ == $0

  mg = EnglishToPigLatin.new
  mg.create

#end
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is while there is still input, get that input, split it up into individual words, and run each word through a Pig Latin conversion method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get input inside of your loop.

Try

```
loop do
  user_input = gets.chomp!
  word_arr = user_input.to_s.split(' ')
  word_arr.each { |x| puts x.engToLatin() + ' '}
  puts "EOF to Quit"
end
```

Otherwise you're trying to get the next line of input when there isn't one.  Additionally, `do` isn't necessary for a `while` statement.
You also don't need to reset `@user_input` to `''`.

And since this is all in a block, you don't need to use instance variables, unless the methods you call need them.

Also your conditional is always true.  `gets` will block until it gets a line of input.  You can use `loop` for an infinite loop that ends on an interrupt.

Also, you needn't flush `STDOUT` if you use a `puts` for the last line there instead of a `print`.

The whole thing could be a script or a method in a module.  An instance doesn't even need to be made.  And if you do, instead of using two lines with your `mg.create`, you should define an `initialize` method.  This is used as a constructor then, and whatever you set when you create an instance should be put there.

It can all be done like this:

```
loop do
  puts gets.chomp.split(' ').map{ |x| x.engToLatin() }.join(' ')
  puts "EOF to Quit"
end
```

Comment: This fixed my current error, but left me with errors later on.  I've updated my original post with more information.

Comment: /media/Storage/Documents/Ruby/EnglishToPigLatin.rb:25: undefined method `string' for "test":String (NoMethodError)
 from /media/Storage/Documents/Ruby/EnglishToPigLatin.rb:23:in `loop'
 `from /media/Storage/Documents/Ruby/EnglishToPigLatin.rb:23`
where 23 is `loop do`

Comment: Oh yes.  Fixed my answer.  You wanted `.to_s`, not `.string`.  Although it's already a string.

Comment: Alright, that fixed it.  Part of the above error was also due to me accidentally commenting out part of my original code.

Comment: Did the original code have `user_input = gets.chomp!` (as in your answer), or `user_input = gets.chomp` ?

Answer (score 2):

Mario's answer is right. But I have the following notes.

- You can still use the `while` construction as below.
- `+' '` implies that you don't want line breaks after each word. I changed that part. `map` and `join` is common in similar cases. `print` does not add a line break while `puts` does.
- I am not sure what you are trying to do with `STDOUT.flush`. If you wanted to scroll to the top of the screen before each output, use `system('clear')`.
- You have a method `entToLatin`, and it should work, but it is a ruby convention to use underscore, like `eng_to_latin` for methods (although there are a few exceptions).

So a more rubyish way would be:

```
def create
  print "Enter the text to be converted to pig latin, EOF to quit: "
  while input = gets.strip and input != 'EOF'
    system('clear')
    puts input.split(/\s+/).map{|x| x.engToLatin}.join(' ')
    puts "EOP to Quit"
  end
end
```

And if you are using ruby 1.9.2, you can shorten `map` so that:

```
def create
  print "Enter the text to be converted to pig latin, EOF to quit: "
  while input = gets.strip and input != 'EOF'
    system('clear')
    puts input.split(/\s+/).map(:engToLatin).join(' ')
    puts "EOP to Quit"
  end
end
```

Comment: That is a good point.  `puts` adds a new line, so @GeoffB should avoid using that if he's trying to print out a sentence on one line.

Comment: @Mario Yes. The OP needs to distinguish between `puts` and `print`. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: So,  `puts` is similar to java's S.O.println, while `print` is similar to java's S.O.print?